# Two fb-messenger bots, same FB page

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I read the documentation for facebook messenger bot but I can't find anywhere if it is possible to make two different FB bots(one test bot) and connect to the same Facebook Page(to use the same webhook. Does someone know if this is possible and is it aginst FB rules?

Comment: Bot to Page is 1:1 mapping. You can't have 2 bots for a single page.

Comment: @Bangdel This is not true since the introduction of handover protocol.

Comment: But what if I have two bots per one page and some fb user tries to send a message to that page. From which bot will come the response?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to investigate the [Handover Protocol (Beta)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/handover-protocol). This will allow you to subscribe two or more apps to the same Facebook page. One of the apps will be configured as the "Primary Receiver", which will have control of any new conversation thread by default. All other apps will be configured as "Secondary Receivers". Any app can pass thread control to another app, but only the Primary Receiver can forcibly take control from another app.

When an app is in control of the thread, it will receive messages on the standard messaging channel. When an app is not in control, it will instead receive them on the [standby channel](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/standby). Standby messages look just like regular messages, except that their entry items contain a "standby" field rather than a "messaging" field.

Here's the kicker: apps are allowed to send messages **whether or not they have thread control**. This means that you cannot rely on the handover protocol to automatically sort out when your bot can and cannot talk. Instead, your bot will need to keep track of whether or not it has control and only respond at the appropriate times. To accomplish this, the [messaging_handovers webhook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_handovers) will be helpful.

Facebook has provided a new version of their page Inbox which supports the Handover Protocol. When configured as a Secondary Receiver, new conversation threads will automatically be filed into the "Done" folder. If one of your apps passes thread control to the Inbox app, the conversation thread will be moved to the "Inbox" folder. When a human page manager clicks the "Done" checkbox on that conversation, the thread is moved back to the "Done" folder, and thread control is passed to the Primary Receiver.

One thing to be aware of, at least as of November 2017, is that the interaction of postback messages with the Handover protocol is a bit unintuitive and possibly even buggy. The [postback documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_postbacks/) indicates that an app will always receive its own postbacks on the standard messaging channel, even if it does not have thread control. From the description of the "title" field of a postback event:

> Title for the CTA that was clicked on. This is sent to all apps subscribed to the page. For apps other than the original CTA sender, the postback event will be delivered via the standby channel.

As the description of the "payload" field indicates though, the standby version of a postback message omits the payload:

> payload parameter that was defined with the button. This is only visible to the app that send the original template message.

I suggest that this is unintuitive because it seems to me "standby" has a different meaning for regular messages than for postback messages. I mention that it might be buggy because I have found my apps often receive their own postbacks on both the messaging and standby channels. (I have taken to ignoring postback messages on the standby channel for this reason.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can subscribe more than one app to the same Page. You will need to designate one as the Primary Receiver role in the page settings, then use the Platform's handover protocol to pass control of the conversation between that apps.

Comment: Hey, do you know how i can assign the primary receiver role programmatically? I mean the only solution i found is that the admin has to go the page settings and manually select the role.

Comment: There’s no way to do it programmatically. Only the page admin can do it in the page settings ui